# Non-singularity of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be any complex matrix, prove that $\ I+A^* A $ is non-singular.

I just need some hint in how to proceed with the question.

Comment: If $(I+A^*A)x=0$ then what can you say about $x^*(I+A^*A)x$ and $x$?

Comment: Won't the former be 0 and x be an eigenvector?

Comment: $0=x^*(I+A^*A)x=x^*x+x^*A^*Ax=\|x\|^2+\|Ax\|^2$ $\Rightarrow x=?$.

Comment: x=0?
Which will imply that I+A*A can't have an eigenvector and therefore it will be non-singular?

Comment: Which will imply that $I+A^*A$ has the trivial kernel (or, if you wish eigenvectors, cannot have the zero eigenvalue) and therefore nonsingular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the matrix is singular then there exists a vector such that,

$$ (I + A^* A) v = 0$$

which implies that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A^*A$ with eigenvalue equal to $-1$.

You should be able to finish the proof from there.

Comment: A singular matrix has 0 as an eigenvalue. You have got that -1 is an eigenvalue. But from here how can we conclude that 0 is not an eigenvalue to get a contradiction?

Comment: I'm assuming that the matrix $I+A^*A$ has an eigenvalue of $0$. This leads to the conclusion that $A^*A$ has an eigenvalue of $-1$. The goal is to show that this is not possible for such a matrix and arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: Eigenvalues of A* are just conjugates of eigenvalues of A. So, if r is an eigenvalue of A then eigenvalue of A*A would be |r|^2. Hence eigenvalues of A*A is always positive?

Comment: @SahibaArora, Thats the key idea. Problem is your answer assumes $A$ itself is diagonalizable, but this might not be true. It is true that $A^*A$ must have positive eigenvalues, think about how the adjoint works in the inner product and look at the hint by A.G. above.